# Error while creating , copy , paste and delete file

Tags: 16.04

in Ubuntu 16.4 although all permission i change in /dev/sdxx and given full privileges but i can not create or delete file , i am new user in Linux and try a lot of commends but still the same error as ( There was an error creating the directory in /mnt/user name)

Answer (score 4):

You don't create files in `/dev/sdaX` directly that is where your filesystem is mounted, and for `/mnt/user` you need to be root to do so.

Now open your terminal and type `cd /home/$USER` and that should place you in your home directory mounted at `/dev/sdxx`. Create files and folders as you wish in there ( `/home/$USER` )

Structure of the root file tree:

```
/
├── bin
├── boot
├── cdrom
├── C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt
├── core
├── dev
├── etc
├── home
├── initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic
├── initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-96-generic
├── lib
├── lib32
├── lib64
├── libx32
├── lost+found
├── media
├── mnt
├── opt
├── proc
├── root
├── run
├── sbin
├── snap
├── srv
├── sys
├── tmp
├── usr
├── var
├── vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic
└── vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
```

Each Ubuntu user has a home directory and that is found in the `home` seen on the `filesystem tree` above. In there you do all things without needing to be `root user` to do so. Please note that you don't mess with the other folders and files seen under the `/` ( root) in the tree shown above. For your `home` directory where you will be when you open `nautilus` Ubuntu's file manager and has a structure as seen below:

```
/home
├── andreas
└── george

1 directory, 1 file
```

In `george` which bears the name I used to create my Ubuntu user, I have all things local to me and to none other user on the system. Here `andreas` is another Ubuntu user and his is different from mine but certain generic files can be found in both like `.bashrc`, `.profile` etc. You want to create folders and files please do so in the `/home/<your_user_name>` folder in my case is george. And this is the structure of `george`:

```
/home/george
├── ~
├── 100
├── 2605430-dzone-internetofthings-2016.pdf-1170824539.pdf
├── anaconda2
├── Anaconda2-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
├── Android
├── android-sdk-linux
├── android-studio
├── AndroidStudioProjects
├── apachetemplates
├── apple
├── apple-el-capitan
├── apples.txt
├── apples.txt~
├── Aptana_Studio_3
├── aspnet
├── bin
├── Bonnie.12717
├── boot-repair
├── bootstrapstudio
├── Boxcryptor_Portable_Linux64_2.20.209.0
├── build
├── Capture
├── certbot-auto
├── che-docs
├── che-sample
├── clamav-0.99
├── clamav-0.99.1
├── C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt
├── Code
├── codeblock-docs
├── code.txt
├── conky-1.10.6
├── css-build
├── database
├── date.out
├── debian-8.4.0-amd64-CD-1.jigdo
├── debian-8.4.0-amd64-CD-1.template
├── debian-8.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso.list
├── debian-8.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso.tmp
├── debian-8.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso.tmpdir
├── debian-8.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.jigdo
├── debian-8.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.jigdo.unpacked
├── debian-8.4.0-amd64-DVD-1.template
├── debian-shared
├── debug_1.log
├── Desktop
├── dir1
├── dir2
├── Documents
├── dotnet-docs
├── Downloads
├── Dropbox
├── eclipse
├── eclipse-che-4.5.1
├── eclipse-docs
├── electron.help.js
├── emacs-24.5
├── emacs-25.1
├── emmet.html~
├── EOF
├── errors
├── examples.desktop
├── ez_setup.py
├── fastcomet-ftp
├── fiddler
├── Fiddler2
├── firefox_dev
├── firefox-quantum
├── FoxitSoftware
├── fs_mark-3.3
├── geor
├── git-docs
├── glassfish-4.1.1
├── Google Drive
├── go-pear.phar
├── hert
├── Homestead
├── hotspot
├── hplip-3.16.8
├── hplip-3.16.8.run
```

I have cut of some other files and folders as it's too long but this is the `home` folder of user `george` and some files youe see here are default others have beenn added by me over time. Please take some time to familiarize yourself with Linux filesystem so you don't mess yours up.

Open your terminal and run `lsblk -f` and you would see some thing similar to this:

```
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL            UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                   
├─sda1 vfat                      B35B-35B8                            /boot/efi
├─sda2 ext4                      43bdfb68-9917-4937-aa5a-932bd2a94c98 /
└─sda3 swap                      e0ca0a52-fd55-459f-820a-be3531e21800 [SWAP]
sr0                                                                   
sr1    iso9660  etisalat-Nigeria 2015-05-19-10-01-25-00               /media/george/etisalat-Nigeria2
loop0  squashfs                                                       /snap/core/2774
loop1  squashfs                                                       /snap/canonical-livepatch/22
loop2  squashfs                                                       /snap/canonical-livepatch/21
loop3  squashfs                                                       /snap/canonical-livepatch/25
loop4  squashfs                                                       /snap/core/2844
loop5  squashfs                                                       /snap/core/2898
```

The entry or line `sda2` is mounted on `/` and that's where all my folders and files for my Ubuntu are and that's what was seen in the `root file tree` previously. Note this can be different for other Ubuntu users as there may decide to divide up their mount points, but no matter how they divide it up Ubuntu will place all of them on a virtual filesystem (VFS) that starts or begins at `/`, which is called root in Linux terminology. So `/`(root) is where it all starts.

Please note that Ubuntu will not just let you create files and folders in the `/` ( root) location, you need to do so as a special user or admin user using the `sudo` command. But please play around with your `/home/your_username` directory after dus familiarization with Linux then you can play with other restricted filesystem locations.